# Truffle tests not resetting account states

Tags: truffle, testrpc, testing

I've written some truffle tests that interact with the account balances. 
Example:

A contract transfers X amount of ether from account A to account B.

Surprisingly the state of the accounts (especially the balances) are not reset between test cases. Meaning tests that test balance transfers cannot be deterministic. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5):

When running [Truffle JavaScript tests](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/javascript-tests) using [Ganache](http://truffleframework.com/ganache/) or [ganache-cli](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli), there is nothing to do: **[Truffle resets the blockchain state between each test](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/testing-your-contracts/#clean-room-environment)**. The initial snapshot is done just after loading the contracts.

More precisely, the state is reset before each `contract` (Truffle replacement for mocha's `describe`). For example:

```
var MyContract = artifacts.require("./MyContract.sol");

contract('MyContract - A', function(accounts) {
  before("Setup", async function () {
    // Suppose balance of accounts[0] == 100ETH
  });

  it("should do Alpha", async function() {
    // Balance of accounts[0] == 100ETH
    decreaseAcount0By1ETH();
    // Balance of accounts[0] == 99ETH
  });

  it("should do Beta", async function() {
    // Balance of accounts[0] == 99ETH,
    // because state is *not* reset between 'it'
  });

contract('MyContract - B', function(accounts) {
  it("should do Alpha", async function() {
    // Balance of accounts[0] == 100ETH again,
    // because state is reset between 'contract'
  });
});
```

This is something you can track in Ganache logs. Look for `evm_snapshot` and `evm_revert`.

Comment: The documentation for Truffle's Clean Room testing  was moved to [here](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/testing-your-contracts/#clean-room-environment)

Comment: Fixed! Thank you @JimmyBosse for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, if you want deterministic tests you need to use `testrpc` with some special params before each test.

Something like:

```
let web3 = new Web3('ws://localhost:8546');
let testrpc;

before(function(done) {
  testrpc = TestRPC.server({
    ws: true,
    gasLimit: 5800000,
    total_accounts: 10,
    seed: 1
  });

  testrpc.listen(8546, '127.0.0.1');
  done();
});
```

More info at: https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc

Comment: Any updates for how this might be done now that `testrpc` has become [`ganache-cli`](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli)?

Comment: @DerekChiang It's automatic, see http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/testing#clean-room-environment . I posted an answer to clarify.